# Any key-value storages with emphasis on compression?

Tags: compression, distributed, key-value-store

Are there any key-value storages which fit the following criteria?

- are open-source
- persistent file storage
- have replication and oplog
- have configurable compression usable for storing 10-100 megabytes of raw text per second
- work on windows and linux

Desired interface should contain at least:

- store a record by a text or numeric ID
- retrieve a record by ID

Comment: how much data are you planning to store in it?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk dozens of terabytes

Comment: What did you end up using? I have exactly the same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

[wiredtiger](http://www.wiredtiger.com/) does support different kind of compression:

> Compression considerations
>
> WiredTiger compresses data at several stages to preserve memory and
>   disk space. Applications can configure these different compression
>   algorithms to tailor their requirements between memory, disk and CPU
>   consumption. Compression algorithms other than block compression work
>   by modifying how the keys and values are represented, and hence reduce
>   data size in-memory and on-disk. Block compression on the other hand
>   compress the data in its binary representation while saving it on the
>   disk.
>
> Configuring compression may change application throughput. For
>   example, in applications using solid-state drives (where I/O is less
>   expensive), turning off compression may increase application
>   performance by reducing CPU costs; in applications where I/O costs are
>   more expensive, turning on compression may increase application
>   performance by reducing the overall number of I/O operations.
>
> WiredTiger uses some internal algorithms to compress the amount of
>   data stored that are not configurable, but always on. For example,
>   run-length reduces the size requirement by storing sequential,
>   duplicate values in the store only a single time (with an associated
>   count).

wiredtiger support different kind of compression:

- key prefix
- dictionary
- huffman
- and block compression which support among other things lz4, snappy, zlib and zstd.

Have look at the [documentation](http://source.wiredtiger.com/2.9.3/tune_page_size_and_comp.html#compression_considerations) for full cover of the subject.